# Save user uploaded file to server using Python

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine, drag-and-drop, google-cloud-storage

I have a small drag and drop file upload app that I was looking to rewrite using Python on App Engine, and plan to save files on Google Cloud Storage. The problem is, I can't figure out how (or if) I can save files in Python. Currently, when the user drags a file into the upload area, Javascript acts on it and sends it off to a PHP file. There I can then save the file to a specific directory on a server by doing something like this:

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, getcwd()."/".$name);
```

My question is, can I use Python to replace the PHP? If so, what am I looking for, as I haven't been able to find anything on this topic. I understand that I cannot save files to App Engine and will be using Google Cloud Storage. How can I do this? Is there a generic way to do this assuming I'm on my own server? Thanks!

Edit: Ignoring the drag and drop portion, can I simply use html to have users browse for a file on their desktop but use Python to take that file and save it somewhere?

Comment: You need to start out by reading what appengine can and can't do. FOr starters it won't allow you to write the file system.  You need to store the file int he datatstore (limit 1MB) or GCS Google CLoud Storage.  You wont' get far without doing your homework.

Comment: I edited the question slightly. I realize that, and thanks for pointing it out. More importantly than making it work on App Engine specifically, can I make this work in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned you wont be able to save the file to the filesystem but you can store the file in the datastore (1Mb limit) or the blobstore (32Mb limit?).
This link provides an example on using the blobstore to upload a file https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Uploading_a_Blob

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I can use Python to do this without using the blobstore? I am kind of looking for the most general way to do this. I have revised my question to make things more clear.

Comment: There is no way to save a file on app engine that doesn't involve using either the data store or the blob store. I think your question needs some work, it is unclear if you are trying to make this work on your own server or on Google App Engine.

Comment: I realized that I am uncertain of what I need at this time. Your answer got me thinking straight and helped me better understand what I am after. Thanks!